# how to find all links and edges in within a circumference?

Tags: julia, openstreetmap

In the openstreetmapX.jl package how to find all the nodes that are within in 1 and 2-5 miles of a certain points? And how to draw a boundary in a map network?

For example, this is the map data:

```
using OpenStreetMapX
# you can replace the line below with a String representing another path to an OSM map file.
map_file_path = joinpath(dirname(pathof(OpenStreetMapX)),"..","test/data/reno_east3.osm")
mx = get_map_data(map_file_path, use_cache=false);
```

if `A=(lat,long)` be a random coordinate inside this map, how to:
1- have all the nodes and links within 1 km away of `A`
2- have all the nodes and links within 2 to 5 km away from `A` (not including those that are less than 1)
3- drawing above boundaries on the map

in the documentation there is `mx.bounds` but it is not for finding a distance from a particular node. Is there any useful command?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a node `140002490` in your example map.
Than you can do

All nodes within 350 meters (node the second vector contains distances in meters):

```
julia> nodes_within_driving_distance(mx,[140002490],350.0)
([3149568822, 1897440773, 140002490, 140293909], [336.19640743008256, 322.421892817634, 0.0, 300.2801993285697])
```

All nodes within 15 seconds (note the second parameter contains driving times):

```
julia> nodes_within_driving_time(mx,[140002490],15.0)
([3149568822, 140293915, 3149568876, 1897440773, 140002490, 140293909], [12.103070667482973, 12.68859012113578, 14.95081063503372, 11.607188141434824, 0.0, 10.81008717582851])
```

If you want to calculate an Euclidean distance use [ENU coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates) which are also the best for plotting.

For an example this will yield approximately 322 which is the distance between those nodes in meters.

```
distance(mx.nodes[140002490], mx.nodes[1897440773])
```

Regarding plotting. ENU coordinates are perfect if you do the plotting yourself (they are also used by OpenStreetMapXPplot.jl). If you use library such as folium than it uses LLA coordinates and in the OpenStreetMapX tutorial you can find examples how to convert ENU to LLA.

Comment: Yes, `nodes_within_driving_distance` is a good choice. But this gives nodes whithin some distance threshold. I need all the edges too. In your example, all the edges by `[3149568822, 1897440773, 140002490, 140293909]`. And the difficult part for me is that I need to threshold 1 and 5 miles. But for 5 miles, I need to remove all nodes that are already within 1 km distance.

Comment: For plotting ENU allows for find the boundary? I don't want to plot all nodes. I need to draw a boundary of 1 and 5 miles from a  node ` 140002490 `. What's the easiest option for this?

Comment: ENU is measured in meters from the reference point. For small areas you can assume there is no curvature and just draw a circle like on any 2d canvas (depending on the actual plotting library you use). So this is just like drawing any other circle. Regarding your first question there might be many routes to a vertex within a distance. Perhaps for this type of customization you could use Dijkstra from Graphs.jl

Comment: thanks for your help. Is it necessary to conduct rotting? I don't want to find routes, just need to know hoe nodes are connected to each other. For instance `[3149568822, 1897440773, 140002490, 140293909]` these are 4 nodes are within 350 distance away from  node `140002490`. But how they from edges is my question?

Comment: You need routes so you have all nodes and all edges.  I think for your business problem you most likely need a custom Dijkstra implementation but maybe start having a look at Graphs.dijkstra_shortest_paths (this works with OpenStreetMapX data as a map has field `g` representing a graph from Graphs.jl)

Comment: Most likely what you are looking for are *isochrone maps* which are not implemented in Julia (as far as I know) and are very non trivia to generate (however some other map server tools exist)

Comment: is there any command similar to `has_edge(g,i,j)` which is available in graph.jl in osmx? I try to not use routingas much as possible.

Comment: You can do `has_edge(mx.h,i,j)` or ` edges(mx.g)` or look at `mx.e` which has a vector of all edges on the map, Finally, `mx.w` is a sparse array that stores values where an edge exists.